How to shift line bar graph in chart.js
I am using chart.js to render a bar graph with a line graph overlay. Basically I'm showing revenue vs expenses with the line graph being the net income for the period. I'm showing last year as a second bar graph next to the this year bar graph and I'm having troubles setting the line graph to be 'over' a certain bar graph. It keeps centering in the 'column'  (see picture). How do I move the position of the line graph to be like the yellow line in the picture?

Here's my code for rendering the graphs:
new Chart(document.getElementById(_this.chartNetId), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Revenue',
                        data: oRev,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: oRev.map((data, index) => data.bgcolor), 
                        stack: '1',
                        order: 1,

                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Rev. Last Per',
                        data: oRevLastPer,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: oRevLastPer.map((data, index) => data.bgcolor), 
                        stack: 'previous',
                        order: 1,
                    },
                                          
                    {
                        label: 'Expense',
                        data: oExp,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: oExp.map((data, index) => data.bgcolor), 
                        stack: '1',
                        order: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Exp. Last Per',
                        data: oExpLastPer,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: oExpLastPer.map((data, index) => data.bgcolor), 
                        stack: 'previous',
                        order: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Net',
                        data: oNI,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        type: 'line',
                        backgroundColor: 'black',
                        borderColor: niCol,
                        borderWidth: 3,
                        tension: .25, // how curved the line is
                        order: 0,
                        stack: 'current'
                    },
                                           
                ]
            },

});
